# Windows 8.1 User left the homegroup and now I have 2 profiles and I ned the info to merge

Tags: windows-8.1, user-profiles, merge, homegroup

I am running Windows 8.1 I am the only user. Well I made the mistake of leaving the homegroup and now I have two profiles. I need to get these profiles to merge. This is causing chaos because now when I try to save a file or jpg, etc. I get an error that tells me I don't have permission to make changes on the network.

Any help woud be great. I just reset my hard drive after having this same issue but at I wasn't certain that was the problem. By the time I noticed the issues I couldn't be sure that was the cause. So now I have diagnosed it happening after making that change and I would love to not have to reset everything again.